# Problem with opening a .msg file for outlook

Tags: windows-7, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with opening a .msg file for outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/208403/problem-with-opening-a-msg-file-for-outlook)

Hi all:

People having problems with opening a file I send to them, here is the scenario when ever I upload a file with extension of .msg or .txt or any other file extension say to the project management site, then someone else downloads it they can not open it the message says:

```
file may not exist, you may not have permissions to open it...... click properties to check permission for the folder.
```

If I upload the same file on the web using windows xp it can be opened by any one, but I am using windows 7 ultimate and I am suspecting something to do with windows 7. Here is another catch if I use Google docs it's can be opened normally.

Using windows 7 ultimate, and office 2007 and 2010. Bit-locker is off.

Comment: exact duplicate of your previous post: [Problem with opening a .msg file for outlook](http://superuser.com/questions/208403/problem-with-opening-a-msg-file-for-outlook)

Comment: yes I am looking for answers :)