# Problem with opening a .msg file for outlook

Tags: windows-7, permissions

People having problems with opening a file I send to them, here is the scenario when ever I upload a file with extension of .msg or .txt or any other file extension say to the project management site, then someone else downloads it they can not open it the message says:

```
file may not exist, you may not have permissions to open it...... click properties to check permission for the folder.
```

If I upload the same file on the web using windows xp it can be opened by any one, but I am using windows 7 ultimate and I am suspecting something to do with windows 7. Here is another catch if I use Google docs it's can be opened normally.

Using windows 7 ultimate, and office 2007 and 2010. Bit-locker is off.

Comment: How do you try to open the file? With windows explorer or with Office?

Comment: Do you generate the file using exactly the same software on XP and 7 and which? How do you upload it? How do your clients download it?

Comment: I upload it to a web site a project management site, I upload as any other file like .txt or .doc.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely caused by an add-in that is installed. Try to open Outlook in safe mode and see if you have the same problem.

http://thedailyreviewer.com/outlook/view/the-file-may-not-exist-you-may-not-have-permission-to-open-it-104713783

Comment: I disabled anti virus add on but I am still having the same problem.